# Make pictureBox follow another (Enemie AI)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So, I want to put a pictureBox (Zombie) to follow another (Player).
How to detect the player's axis comparing with the zombie's?!

Comment: What axis are you referring to?

Comment: He's most likely referring to x,y coordinates assigned to the Location property of each picturebox.

Comment: @Areks: If so, I wonder why the question doesn't start with how to position the player in the first place.

Comment: **[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345446/make-an-object-move-towards-another-objects-position)** the last answer is very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Left` and `Top` properties from both objects and compare the distance that way.

```
  var zombieLeft = pictureBoxZombie.Left;
  var playerLeft = pictureBoxPlayer.Left;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox_properties.aspx

Comment: How to compare those?! I tried "if (zombie.Left == Left)"